# Using Phonegap's Facebook access token on the server-side

Tags: facebook, phonegap-plugins

I have **Phonegap's** Facebook plugin working perfectly within my Android app.  This plugin uses Facebook's client-side Javascript flow.  However, I would like to upload photos to FB from the server-side, instead of client-side, as this is much (much) more efficient.

Is it possible to use Facebook's access token generated from client-side on the server-side?  (BTW, I have Facebook's PHP SDK working perfectly on stand alone web pages.)

I am getting a `"(#200) Permissions Error"` trying to pull this off.

If the client-side token cannot be used on the server, any other suggestions?  I do not know of a way to generate a server-side Facebook token from a Phonegap app.

**Edit:**
It appears that you actually *can* use a client side Facebook token on the server.  It's simple matter of upgrading to the latest Facebook PHP SDK, and using the `$facebook->setAccessToken()` function with a token sent from Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An access token is valid via client or server. On facebook end it is the same thing: a request through HTTP.

If you are not able to upload photos, check that you have the appropriate user permissions for your application.

If you are trying to figure out what graph api calls you need, a good starting place is the javascript console:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

Here you can see in the javascript what calls are being made in order to read fromt he api, or make a feed story or upload. You will use the same graph URLS and variables using server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use client side token in server side.Actually when user is logged into facebook ,fb create an access token in cookies ,which you can access on both client as well as server and when user is logged out ,cookie is destroyed and access token becomes invalid.

And to upload the photos to facebook i used following code :

// $friends is an array of friend id to be tagged in photo

// $x and $y are the position of tags.

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($friends);$i++)
{
$tags[] =  array(
      'tag_uid'=>$friends[$i],
      'x'      => $x[$i],
      'y'      => $y[$i],
 );
}



$photo_details = array(
'access_token'=>$access_token ,
    'message'=> 'Any message',
'tags' => $tags
);

$file=$photo_name; //Example image file

$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```